# creating a stored procedure using columns from different tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have 4 tables: `customer(PK custId)`, `order(PK orderID)` and `orderitem(PK orderItemId)` and `products(PK ProductID)`

the orderitem table has productID and OrderItemID as Foreign keys to products and orders respectively.

```
Orderitem:
-----------------------
orderID | productID | OrderItemID 



Products:
-------------------------------- 
productID | unitcost | OrderItem
```

table has quantity columns ,

i want to create a stored procedure that will calculate totalcost column in orderItem using the values from unitcost from products table and  quantity from  orderItems tables.

also if possible ,how can i get the `orderID` in the procedure to come from `Orders` table as it is the PK and FK to `orderItem` table

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 R2, thanks for your concern to my question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly a base query for your stored procedure might look like this

```
SELECT i.*,
       p.unitcost * i.quantity totalcost
  FROM orderitem i INNER JOIN
       order o ON i.orderID = o.orderID INNER JOIN
       products p ON i.productID = p.ProductID
 WHERE i.orderID = 12345
```

*If you specify which RDMBS you're using then it'll be possible to help you to wrap it in a SP.*

Comment: yes that's correct. the stored proc is my prob as in the orderItem table i only have orderId , ProductId  and quantity columns. i am using sql 2008 R2

Comment: thanks alot Peter. i managed to get to that point. i also do have the totalcost column created in the orderItem table but it currently has null values so the sp must calculate and insert the total value into that column.